# No implicits found for parameter ev: Any <:< (T_, U_)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a map based on conditions. Here's the general workflow in pseudocode:

```
def createMyMap(input: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val stringArray = input.split(",")

  stringArray.map(element => {
    if (condition) {
      newKey -> newVal
    }
  }).toMap
}
```

and I see two compile errors:

1. `No implicits found for parameter ev: Any <:< (T_, U_)` in the `toMap` call
2. For the method `createMyMap`

```
Type mismatch.
Required: scala.Predef.Map [String, String]
Found: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing, Nothing]
```

This makes sense since the compiler doesn't know how to create the map if the condition isn't fulfilled. For example, if I add this in the method:

```
if (condition) {
  newKey -> new Val
} else {
  null
}
```

then it'll compile. I'm just not too sure how to approach the `else` - how do I avoid this kind of problem? I'm running into this because I only want to create a map entry if a condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Use `collect` or `flatMap` + `Option` instead of `map`

Comment: Would recommend using `collect` as that's it's main functionality, as a filter + map 2 in 1 method.

Comment: @Akhil I got flatMap + Option to work, but a bit confused on using collect. Is just replacing `map` with `collect` not enough?

Comment: @stackoverflowflowflwofjlw no, collect expects a partial function, like “.collect { case elem if condition => … }”

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how `newKey` and `newVal` are derived, but here is the template code using `collect`

```
def createMyMap(input: String): Map[String, String] =
  input.split(",").collect {
    case s if <condition> =>
      newKey -> newVal
  }.to(Map)
```

e.g.

```
def createMyMap(input: String): Map[String, String] =
  input.split(",").collect {
    case s if s.contains('.') =>
      s -> "data"
  }.to(Map)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few good options that I'll summarize from the comments:

1. `filter` + `map` + `toMap`

```scala
// stringArray: Traversable[String]
// condition: String => Boolean
// transform: String => (String, String)

val result: Map[String, String] = stringArray
  .filter(condition)
  .map(transform)
  .toMap
```

2. `map` + `flatten` + `toMap`

```scala
val result: Map[String, String] = stringArray
  .map { k =>
    if (condition(k)) Some(transform(k))
    else None
  }
  .flatten
  .toMap
```

3. `flatMap` + `toMap`

```scala
val result: Map[String, String] = stringArray
  .flatMap { k =>
    if (condition(k)) Some(transform(k))
    else None
  }
  .toMap
```

4. `collect` + `toMap`

```scala
val result: Map[String, String] = stringArray
  .collect {
    case k if condition(s) => transform(k)
  }
  .toMap
```

[See documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/View$$FlatMap.html#collect%5BB%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BA,B%5D):CC%5BB%5D).

In short, methods `3` and `4` are especially clean (although all are good IMO). However, the one that is semantically the most readable IMO is `4`, which uses `collect` (with option `1` being a close second).

Comment: If you are summarising the comments, please mark the answer as community wiki so that you don't take credit for others work.

Comment: Not really taking credit, but sure, don't mind making this a community answer.